# Github, Puttygen, & Pageant: Permission Denied (publickey)

Tags: github, rsa, putty, msysgit

I'm using msysgit on Windows 7 as well as [the PuTTY suite](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/).

I opened Puttygen and clicked the "Generate" button. I moved my cursor around to "generate some randomness". After the key was created, I entered a passphrase for the key and clicked "Save private key". I saved the file as "private.ppk" in the directory `c:/Users/Kristen/.ssh`.

Then I clicked "save public key" and saved the file as "public.pub" inside `c:/Users/Kristen/.ssh`.

Then I copied the contents of the field labeled "Public key for pasting into OpenSSH authorized_keys file". I did *not* copy the contents of the `public.pub` file, because I know that has extra data that will break the key.

I went to my GitHub account, went to Settings > SSH Keys, and clicked the "Add SSH key" button. I gave they key a title, then pasted in the key I copied from Puttygen and clicked "Add Key". The key was saved successfully.

I opened Pageant and clicked "Add Key". I selected the file "public.ppk" from `c:/Users/Kristen/.ssh`. I entered the passphrase.

I opened Git bash and typed `ssh git@github.com`. It asked me if I wanted to add github.com to the list of known hosts. I typed `yes`. Then I got this error:

> Permission denied (publickey).

Then I typed `ssh -v git@github.com` and got this output:

[image]

I saw that it was looking for `id_rsa`, so I created a directory named `id_rsa` and placed my keys inside it.

Then I typed `ssh git@github.com` again, and got this message:

> Enter passphrase for key `c:/Users/Kristen/.ssh/id_rsa:`

I entered the passphrase for my private key but it kept asking again and again.

Then I deleted that folder and changed the name of my private key to `id_rsa.ppk`, but got the same "Permission denied (publickey)" message.

I went into Control Panel > System > System Properties > Advanced > Environment Variables, and my `GIT_SSH` variable is set to `c:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY\plink.exe`, and I confirmed that Plink does live in that folder.

Not sure what else to try. Suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

> I saw that it was looking for the private key in a folder called `id_rsa`.

No, I can assure you, `id_rsa` would be the name of a private ssh key *file*, *not* a directory.

Your keys should be in `%HOME%/.ssh`, but if you are using plink and pageant (and *not* openssh), make sure the environment variable `GIT_SSH` reference `plink.exe`.
See for instance "[How do I set GIT to use `Plink.exe`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2985195/6309)".

[image: env var]

See this [tutorial to generate your keys](http://nathanj.github.com/gitguide/tour.html#pushing).

Comment: Ah, I assumed since `id_rsa` didn't have an extension it was a directory. Anyway, I've confirmed that the path to Plink in my `GIT_SSH` variable is correct, and I've updated my question to include that.

Comment: @kgrote try and regenerate your keys following http://nathanj.github.com/gitguide/tour.html#pushing (and publish the new public key)

Comment: Hmm, it works fine when I `git push`, but not when I use the `ssh` command. Obviously that doesn't really matter, but it's damned annoying.